# Jquery Ajax Returns NOTHING at all

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$('.submit-clickable').click(function (e) {
    let username = document.getElementById('susername');
    let password = document.getElementById('spassword');
    $(this).html("Saving ...");

    if(username != null && password != null) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/board/settings/save',
            data: { username: username, password: password },

            success: function (message) {
                $(this).html("Save Data");
                alert(message);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error Occured!" + " | " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText +
                    " | " + textStatus + " | " +  errorThrown);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

AND

```
<?php

include "system/user.php";
include "system/system.php";

$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;

$username_old = getUsername();
$password_old = getPasswordEncrypted(getId());

if($username != null && $password != null) {
    if(!password_verify($password, $password_old)) {
        updatePassword($password);
        echo '1';
    }

    if($username != $username_old) {
        //todo: Update name
        echo '2';
    }

    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'no-data';
}
```

?>

So, the error is that no matter what I try, there is no response at all. No Error Message, nothing. I tried the link and it says 'no-data' obviesly.

You need some more details? Aks me!

I have to add something, so yeah how was your day?

HTML is here, lol. Why do I have to add this nice stuff:

```
<div class="setting-row">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="name">{{ trans('common.name') }}</div>
                    <input type="text" class="show-input" id="susername" placeholder="{{ trans('common.name') }}" value="{{ getUsername() }}">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="name">{{ trans('common.email') }} <span>Disabled</span></div>
                    <input type="text" class="show-input" id="semail" placeholder="{{ trans('common.email') }}" value="{{ getMail() }}" disabled>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="name">{{ trans('common.password') }}</div>
                    <input type="text" class="show-input" id="spassword" placeholder="New password here">
                </div>

                <div class="submit">
                    <button class="submit-clickable">Save Data</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Give more details!

Comment: I'm going to try the following: The User can update the username, etc in frontend and now I have to pass it into backend -> get answer from backend to show error or success message

Comment: There are many factors that could result in blank response. You need to inspect what's happening on the network. is the event getting fired? sent? does it receive a status code? are there console errors? Try using console and network tabs in chrome devtools. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: For one, "this" variable in line $(this).html("Save Data"); would be invalid since you're in a callback. This could throw error and stop executing. beyond the line.

Comment: Question says JQuery but code has JS. document.getElementById is JS, use $("#my_id") instead (that's JQuery)

Answer (score 0):

change these lines:

```
    let username = document.getElementById('susername');
    let password = document.getElementById('spassword');
```

to:

```
    username = document.getElementById('susername').value;
    password = document.getElementById('spassword').value;
    console.log('username: '+username);
    console.log('password:'+password);
```

and it should work.

Comment: First of all thank you. But to my disappointment it does not work either.

Comment: has to be something related to the data coming in, just tried it on codepen sans if statement and it fires the error. double check that you have values being checked by that

Comment: update your question please, comments aren't meant for code.

Comment: updated my code to see what data is being sent , can you add this line and see what is the output in console

Comment: this answer solves the problem. I'm not seeing a reason why you're not getting a response. I just tried it with your exact HTML and JS using .value to get the text input and it fires the error. Before that you should receive an illegal invocation error. please see this codepen for example. https://codepen.io/calebswank11/pen/RQpQEr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164867/discussion-between-caleb-swank-and-satya).